# Redirect webpage if date & time in url querystring has past

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have one webpage that loads different content from links with querystrings that I build manually. I want to add a datetime parameter to the links, such as encode 12/30/2018 19:30:00 as datetime=12/30/2018%2019%3A30%3A00, then in the webpage C# code it would parse link and stay on the page if it is before the datetime, or, redirect to a different page if it is past the datetime. How can I mock up the code in C# codebehind to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For questions such as this we would expect some code as to what you have tried already, with some summary of how it is failing to meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following in the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var param = Request.QueryString["datetime"];

        if (DateTime.TryParse(param, out DateTime result))
        {
            if (DateTime.Now > result)
            {
                Response.Redirect("wherever");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the 2nd DateTime (within the TryParse bool) in order to get it to work, and reference it as:

    public partial class wl_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    private DateTime result;


After that, it works great, thanks so much!